# export from Excel to Oracle

Tags: vba, excel, oracle11g, odbc, instantclient

I have a project where I have to send data from an Excel spreadsheet to an Oracle database.

Here is the code I am using but it is not working, I am getting errors in the `strSQL` statements at the second string statement.  I am trying to use an Excel range name to `Insert` or `Update` into an Oracle database.

```
Const hostName = "host"
Const portNo = "port"
Const srvSID = "SID"
Const usrID = "username"
Const usrPwd = "password"

Sub ADOInsert()
Dim cnAdo As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConnString As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
'set the worksheet:
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IMPDATA")
Dim Imprange As Range
Set Imprange = ws1.Range("a2:d6")

    strDriver = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};"
    strParams = "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + hostName + ")(PORT=" + portNo + "))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" + srvSID + ")));"
    strUser = "UID=" + usrID + ";PWD=" + usrPwd + ";"

    strConnString = strDriver + strParams + strUser


    Set cnAdo = New ADODB.Connection
    cnAdo.Open strConnString

    '/ this is hardcoded for number of rows and columns.
    For lngRow = 1 To 10
        strSQL = "Insert Into TESTDATA1"'/ 
        strSQL = strSQL & "'" & Range(Imprange, 1).Value & "', "   '/ REQUEST_NUMBER
        strSQL = strSQL & "'" & Range(Imprange, 2).Value & "', "   '/ CID
        strSQL = strSQL & "'" & Range(Imprange, 3).Value & "', "   '/ SERVER_TYPE
        strSQL = strSQL & "'" & Range(Imprange, 4).Value & "' "    '/ COST
        cnAdo.Execute strSQL
    Next
    cnAdo.Close
    Set cnAdo = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We're more here to help with errors you're getting, and certainly not here to write for you. I suggest searching online for a guide and following it. We can help with any troubles you run into along the way. Please do also pass through this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), which will help your questions get more valuable answers and attention.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to go is to convert the Excel file to the `.csv` format, and then you can use the SQL loader creating your own control file, or else you can create an external table pointing to your `.csv` file. Otherwise you can parse your `.csv` file programmatically and load each row on your table using ODBC, JDBC, and so on.

Comment: requirement is to send via excel